Bokeh, Time Series plot with custom Save tool
the following code is an example from bokeh documentation:

import numpy as np

from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, RangeTool
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.sampledata.stocks import AAPL

dates = np.array(AAPL['date'], dtype=np.datetime64)
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(date=dates, close=AAPL['adj_close']))

p = figure(height=300, width=800, tools="xpan", toolbar_location=None,
           x_axis_type="datetime", x_axis_location="above",
           background_fill_color="#efefef", x_range=(dates[1500], dates[2500]))

p.line('date', 'close', source=source)
p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Price'

select = figure(title="Drag the middle and edges of the selection box to change the range above",
                height=130, width=800, y_range=p.y_range,
                x_axis_type="datetime", y_axis_type=None,
                tools="", toolbar_location=None, background_fill_color="#efefef")

range_tool = RangeTool(x_range=p.x_range)
range_tool.overlay.fill_color = "navy"
range_tool.overlay.fill_alpha = 0.2

select.line('date', 'close', source=source)
select.ygrid.grid_line_color = None
select.add_tools(range_tool)

show(column(p, select))


I am curious, is it possible to add a custom SaveTool that saves the whole figure instead of the currently displayed part of it? To be more precise, suppose the range of the domain is equal to (0,1000), but x_range in the figure options is set to (0, 200), then the default SaveTool will save the plot with x_range equal to (x+0, x+200), where x is the starting position of the currently displayed part of the figure. But I want the SaveTool to save the whole plot, i.e. range should be equal to (0,1000).

Not really. The toolbar SaveTool is purely browser-based and just dumps the raw pixel data from the HTML canvas that the plot is drawn on into a PNG image. There are Python APIs for saving PNGs from plot or layout objects directly, so you could potentially create a second version of the plot just for exporting. But this would require running things as a Bokeh Server appliation so that a save button could trigger actual Python callback code.
